# Can't create new tablespace

Tags: linux, postgresql

I am trying to create a new tablespace:

```
>CREATE TABLESPACE db2 LOCATION '/mnt/database2/db2';
>ERROR:  directory "/mnt/database2/db2" does not exist
```

But the directory is exists:

```
>[ -d '/mnt/database2/db2' ]&& echo ¨exists¨||echo ¨not exists¨  
>¨exists¨
```

What can be wrong?

UPD:

```
# \! ls /mnt/database2/db2
# \! ls /mnt/database2/db3
ls: cannot access /mnt/database2/db3: No such file or directory
#  CREATE TABLESPACE db2 LOCATION '/mnt/database2/db2';
ERROR:  directory "/mnt/database2/db2" does not exist
#  CREATE TABLESPACE db2 LOCATION '/mnt/database2/db3';
ERROR:  directory "/mnt/database2/db3" does not exist
```

Comment: Did you run the second command on the database *server*? Does user `postgres` have permission to write to the directory?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) I even run " chown postgres /mnt/database2/db2" command to set postgres as owner of directory

Comment: and if yourun in `psql` `\! ls /mnt/database2/db2` ?..

Comment: output is empty:

Comment: what os is that? and if you `ls /mnt/database2/db2` in shell?..

Comment: #cat /etc/*-release
ALT Linux 6.0.0 Centaurus  (Cheiron)

Comment: and shell output of `ls /mnt/database2/db2`?..

Comment: shell output is empty too

Comment: https://docs.altlinux.org/ru-RU/archive/6.0/html-single/centaurus/index.html#sysconfig Помощь сообщества - I would ask guys why you cant list directories in first place. this question is not about postgres, but about ALT linix I'd say

Comment: Run `strace` on the backend while `CREATE TABLESPACE` is running. You should be able to find the problem.

Comment: @АлександрОпарин `if [[ -d /mnt/database2/db2 ]]; then echo exists; else echo "does not exist"; fi` please